# XML repete registro ao ser gerado em PHP

Tags: php, xml

tenho um script PHP que gera arquivo XML, porém algo muito estranho é que ele repete vários registros da minha tabela de imóveis e o pior ainda é que não existe imóveis repetidos. Repete o ID do imóvel sendo que há somente um imóvel para cada ID.

Segue meu código que gera o XML:

```
$arquivo = "nuroa.xml";
$ponteiro = fopen($arquivo, "w");
fwrite($ponteiro, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
fwrite($ponteiro, '<nuroa>');

$sqlguiatexto = "SELECT id FROM imoveis";
$rsqlguiatexto = mysql_query($sqlguiatexto)
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta ao banco de dados");

while($roweditusertexto = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlguiatexto))
   {

       $conteudo .= '<ad>';
       $conteudo .= '<id><![CDATA['.$roweditusertexto['id'].']]></id>';
       $conteudo .= '</ad>';
       fwrite($ponteiro, $conteudo);

   }

fwrite($ponteiro, '</nuroa>');
fclose($ponteiro);
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está acontecendo para isso? Estranho é que não existe registro repetido.

Aguardo ajuda, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está somando o conteúdo repetidas vezes ao arquivo.

Veja a diferença dentro do `WHILE`:

```
$arquivo = "nuroa.xml";
$ponteiro = fopen($arquivo, "w");
fwrite($ponteiro, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>");
fwrite($ponteiro, '<nuroa>');

$sqlguiatexto = "SELECT id FROM imoveis";
$rsqlguiatexto = mysql_query($sqlguiatexto)
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta ao banco de dados");

while($roweditusertexto = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlguiatexto))
   {
       $conteudo  = '<ad>';
       //        ↑ aqui não vai o ponto, pois é um conteúdo novo.
       $conteudo .= '<id><![CDATA['.$roweditusertexto['id'].']]></id>';
       $conteudo .= '</ad>';
       fwrite($ponteiro, $conteudo);

   }

fwrite($ponteiro, '</nuroa>');
fclose($ponteiro);
```

Comment: Como soluciono?

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini o código na resposta ja é a solução. Em vez de só somar coisas no conteúdo, estamos recriando ele a cada dado. Olhe a diferença do `$conteudo` da 1a linha. No primeiro é `=` no lugar de `.=` - Editei o comentário no código para você achar a diferença.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.